# MAC OSX 10.14.6 /Library/PostgreSQL can't be found in terminal but is showing up during Postgres installation

Tags: postgresql, macos

I'm trying to uninstall/reinstall postgresql.  I've uninstalled postgres using the App Cleaner & Uninstaller, however when I try to reinstall it I get the following message:
[image: error message]

When I look for the PostgreSQL folder in my Library directory it is non existent:

MacBook-Pro-de-Stephen:Library stephenlang$ ls -a

```
.           ColorPickers        FontCollections     LanguageModeling    PubSub          VirtualBox
..          ColorSync       Fonts           LaunchAgents        Python          VoiceTrigger
.DS_Store       Colors          Fonts Disabled      Logs            Receipts        Voices
.localized      Compositions        GameKit         Mail            Safari          WebKit
Accounts        Containers      Google          Messages        SafariSafeBrowsing  Workflows
Address Book Plug-Ins   Cookies         Group Containers    Metadata        Saved Application State Zoiper
Application Scripts CoreData        HomeKit         Mobile Documents    Screen Savers       com.apple.internal.ck
Application Support CoreFollowUp        IdentityServices    News            Services        iMovie
Assistant       DES         Input Methods       PDF Services        Sharing         iTunes
Assistants      Dictionaries        Internet Plug-Ins   Parallels       Social          studentd
Audio           Dropbox         Jupyter         Passes          Sounds
Autosave Information    Family          Keyboard        PersonalizationPortrait Spelling
Caches          Favorites       Keyboard Layouts    PreferencePanes     StickiesDatabase
Calendars       FileProvider        KeyboardServices    Preferences     Suggestions
CallServices        Filters         Keychains       Printers        SyncedPreferences


    MacBook-Pro-de-Stephen:~ stephenlang$ cd Library/PostgreSQL
-bash: cd: Library/PostgreSQL: No such file or directory
```

What could be going on here, and how can I fully uninstall Postgres in order to get a fresh installation?